# Subsequence searching with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, fuzzy-search

I've setup a simple index in Elasticsearch that I want to perform ["Github like"](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/find/master) subsequence searching on:

```
{
  "files" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "file" : {
        "properties" : {
          "name" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "analyzer" : "simple"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then add a document:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/files/file' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "name": "/my/path/to/file.txt"
}
'
```

When I query this with

`"query": { "match": {"name": {"query": "mypath", "fuzziness": "AUTO" }} }`

I get the file back as expected. If I however query with

`"query": { "match": {"name": {"query": "mypathto", "fuzziness": "AUTO" }} }`

the file is no longer returned.

---

Basically I want all subsequences of a document to give a match, e.g.:

- mat/t => /**m**y/p**a**th/**t**o**/**file.t**x**t
- mx => /**m**y/path/to/file.t**x**t
- mypathtofiletxt => /**my**/**path**/**to**/**file.txt**

Comment: did you try using "\*" while queriying like "\*mypath\*" with `query_string`. And you should use highlight feature.

Comment: I would use multi fields here. Other than the "name" field that you have, you can add more fields. For instance: an nGram field with a pattern filter to remove "/". You can configure nGram lengths according to your use case. Query on all the fields (for example: "name" and "name.ngram"). Add as many fields with their own analyzers as you like. 
read: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Comment: As @Ivan explains in his answer, using fuzzy on the name field with the simple/standard analyzer won't get you far, with your use case.

Answer (score 0):

## About Long Term

Simple analyzer splits your file name into set of small tokens:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "simple",
  "text": "/my/path/to/file.txt"
}'
```

This means you have the following terms in your index ["my","path", "to", "file","txt"]

Match query accepts text and analyzes it by using the same analyzer as at index time, i.e.:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_analyze" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "analyzer": "simple",
  "text": "mypathto"
}'
```

So in your case, match query tries to find **mapathto** term. This works in case of small names, because fuzzy query matches your phrase **mypath** by term **path** without 2 symbols(2 editions) **my**path. As a solution you can use the following query:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query": { "match": {"name": {"query": "/my/path/to", "fuzziness": "AUTO" }} }
}'
```

## GitHub Like Query

There is no out-of-the-box solution for this, but you can do the following:

1. Index field as keyword - no analysis = keep as is
2. Only lowercase normalizer is used(not analyzer)
3. Use wildcard query with * between each symbol

Please note that wildcard query can be slow, as it needs to iterate over many terms(internally it uses http://www.brics.dk/automaton/ which is quite optimal and fast for small indexes), so performance depends on the count of unique terms with a similar subsequence. In order to optimize performance you can use unique index for every project. Here is simple example:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "file": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT test/file/1
{
  "name": "/my/path/to/file.txt"
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": { "wildcard": {"name": {"value": "*m*a*t*/*t*"}} }
}

GET test/_search
{
  "query": { "wildcard": {"name": {"value": "*m*x*"}} }
}


GET test/_search
{
  "query": { "wildcard": {"name": {"value": "*m*y*p*a*t*h*t*o*f*i*l*e*t*x*t*"}} }
}
```

Also note that wildcard query does not support analyzers/normalyzers, so you have to lowercase you request on client side.

Comment: That is another search entirely. I need `mypath`, `mypathto` **and** `/my/path/to` to all match the document. Just like if you enter `clsroelbenchtrtaskjava` in the Github link in the question you get `https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/benchmark/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/benchmark/transport/TransportClientBenchmark.java` as a result since it contains all the given characters in the same order.

Comment: @OskarPersson What about this?